# AppIndicator in root

Tags: indicator, application-development

I am coding an gui to create a vpn.

I am using now "AppIndicator" after using "GtkStatusIcon" but the icon works with the normal user but it's not displayed with `sudo` or `gksudo`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The AppIndicator instance should be initiated from an unprivileged user, such as the current logged into desktop. This is is required so D-Bus communication used between the appindicator and the panel to work.

You should probably run your program as a normal user, and use gksudo only on the portions requiring root access.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but if i use gksudo only on the portions the password will be asked every times i want to connect ... :(

Comment: This should not be the case, I know that after using sudo, there is a time span where it doesn't ask for the password again.